# how to show hidden widget in desktop/panel with extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have a toolbar in my desktop. also i have a button on desktop for showing and hiding this toolbar.
at the moment i have extra button for hiding in toolbar itself and its works ok.
if Iam hiding it, toolbar is completely initialized and panel1.object (see code below) looks like this:

> ```
> activeUI: "default"
> autoGenId: true
> body: constructor
> collapseDirection: "top"
> componentCls: "x-panel"
> componentLayout: constructor
> componentLayoutCounter: 2
> container: constructor
> dd: constructor
> dock: "top"
> dockedItems: constructor
> el: constructor
> events: Object
> floatingItems: constructor
> frame: undefined
> hasListeners: HasListeners
> height: 35
> hidden: true
> hiddenByLayout: null
> hiddenOnCollapse: constructor
> hierarchyState: Object
> hierarchyStateInner: Object
> id: "TESTtoolbarX-1034"
> initialConfig: Object
> initialStyle: Object
> items: constructor
> lastBox: Object
> layout: constructor
> layoutCounter: 2
> loader: null
> margin$: Object
> ownerCt: constructor
> ownerLayout: constructor
> plugins: undefined
> pluginsInitialized: true
> protoEl: null
> renderData: Object
> renderSelectors: Object
> rendered: true
> rendering: null
> scrollFlags: Object
> stateEvents: Array[0]
> stateId: undefined
> tools: Array[0]
> ui: "default"
> uiCls: Array[1]
> x: 0
> y: 0
> __proto__: Object
> ```

if i'm trying to SHOW my toolbar with external button on the dekstop my panel1.object is much shorter.

```
autoGenId: true
collapseDirection: "top"
componentCls: "x-panel"
componentLayout: constructor
dockedItems: constructor
events: Object
floatingItems: constructor
hasListeners: HasListeners
height: 35
hiddenOnCollapse: constructor
id: "TESTtoolbarX-1067"
initialConfig: Object
initialStyle: Object
items: constructor
layout: constructor
loader: null
plugins: undefined
pluginsInitialized: true
protoEl: constructor
renderData: Object
renderSelectors: Object
stateEvents: Array[0]
stateId: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

i'm trying to show it like this (Code from Controller):

```
 onShowToolbar: function() {
        debugger;

        var panel1 = Ext.create('TEST.view.desktop.Toolbar', { maxWidth: 360, height: 35 });
        panel1.show();},
```

how i can show this *** toolbar right? please help!

Comment: You want to add toolbar dynamically or show already existing toolbar?

Comment: already exisiting toolbar, it is just hidden. hide works to me, but show not at all.

Comment: In _OnShowToolbar_ you create a new toolbar and showing it. You need to call **.show()** method of hidden toolbar.

Comment: how can i get hidden one? i am very new on extjs, programming it just couple weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example. Panel with toolbar and button. Click on button show or hide toolbar.
View:

```
Ext.define('TEST.view.desktop.Desktop', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.desktop.Desktop',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    hidden: true
                }
            ],
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    action: 'testbutton'
                }
            ]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('TEST.controller.desktop.Desktop', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: ['desktop.Desktop'],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            '[xtype=desktop.Desktop] button[action=testbutton]': {
                click: this.showHideToolbar
            }
        });
    },

    showHideToolbar: function (button) {
        var tb = button.up('panel').down('toolbar');
        if (tb.isVisible()) {
            tb.hide();
        } else {
            tb.show();
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Controller with mouse(over/out):

```
Ext.define('TEST.controller.desktop.Desktop', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: ['desktop.Desktop'],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            '[xtype=desktop.Desktop] button[action=testbutton]': {
                mouseover: this.showToolbar,
                mouseout: this.hideToolbar
            }
        });
    },

    showToolbar: function (button) {
        var tb = button.up('panel').down('toolbar');
        tb.show();
    },

    hideToolbar: function (button) {
        var tb = button.up('panel').down('toolbar');
        tb.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah! works!!! can i make it same without clicking on button, but just with mouseover/out effects???

Comment: Yes. Use **mouseover** and **mouseout** events. More info [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button)

Comment: sorry i'am annoying.подскажи пожалуйста как я могу зделать это с твоим кодом?

Comment: Use English please.`init: function () {
        this.control({
            '[xtype=desktop.Desktop] button[action=testbutton]': {
                mouseover: this.showToolbar,
                mouseout: this.hideToolbar
            }
        });
    },

    showToolbar: function (button) {
        var tb = button.up('panel').down('toolbar');
        tb.show();
    },

    hideToolbar: function (button) {
        var tb = button.up('panel').down('toolbar');
        tb.hide();
    }`

Comment: this.control({
                                          '[xtype=desktop.Desktop] button[action=showHideToolbar]': {
                                              mouseover: this.showToolbar,
                                              mouseout: this.hideToolbar
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }, <------ should it be in VIEW I suppose??